# Should we set off a second modifying phrase before a noun?

Tags: word-choice, syntactic-analysis

I know the question itself is awkward!
I was going to write something like the sentences below, but I was not sure about the punctuation.

1.Evidence on something is scant in global and almost non-existent in national scale.

2.Evidence on something is scant in global, and almost non-existent in national, scale.

Comment: (a) Both would be correct were 'in global / national scale' acceptable. Use whichever aids parsing / reflects smooth speech patterns better (you might have to choose). (b) I'd use _non-existent_.

Comment: What does 'sth' mean?  I can't find it in the dictionary.

Comment: @Clare "sth" is short for "something."

Comment: Thank you @EdwinAshworth I actually wanted to combine "scant in global scale and almost non-existent in national scale" so to make an elliptical phrase with "scale" as the base. And sorry if my descriptions of technical grammatical terms suck!

Comment: Why not write "something" on a site devoted to English language and usage?

Comment: all right @clare now which one is better, if any?!

Comment: *Evidence on something is scant on a global scale and almost non-existent on a national scale* or you can use *national one* if you don't want to repeat *scale*.

Comment: Much obliged @Clare

Comment: Simpler is better: Scant evidence exists nationally or internationally for [etc.]. Not sure scale is right here.

Answer (score 1):

Unless, on something' is there to indicate that you would be including details there, it doesn't add anything and could be omitted, and the order seems to be the wrong way round. I should give the information about the lack of evidence from the smaller area to the larger, for comparison, e.g. 'Evidence is almost non-existent in national scale, and scant (even)in a global scale'.

Comment: in a national scale is not idiomatic.

Comment: I would use "on" rather than "in".